# TS2339: Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'BehaviorSubject<AbstractControl[]

Tags: angular, typescript

I am looking to create a dynamic table using angular material where i can add/remove data dynamically.
Being very new to Angular , i have referred follwing stackblitz to create the table.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-editable-table-fazhbc

While all my changes work - i am not able to sort the data at

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.matSort;
  }
```

The error i get
TS2339:  Property 'sort' does not exist on type `'BehaviorSubject<AbstractControl[]`

is the sorting isn't supported like in material table data source or am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the current value from the BehaviorSubject with either `value` or `getValue()` and sort it like this: `this.dataSource.value.sort(this.matSort)`.

Comment: it doesn't work -
Error TS2345: Argument of type 'MatSort' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: AbstractControl, b: AbstractControl) => number'.
  Type 'MatSort' provides no match for the signature '(a: AbstractControl, b: AbstractControl): number'

Comment: provide an example where your question and the stackblitz match

Comment: This doesn't match your question (e.g. you are not using ngAfterViewInit, u have no member called matSort, …).

Comment: my bad, added the link which i referred for custom table

Answer (score -1):

As BehaviorSubject return observable hence first subscribe that data then apply sort funct

Comment: thanks,could you please share a little more detail ?

Comment: Subject is An special type observable in Rxjs.

Answer (score -1):

You can think of this as a news reporter talking on TV and giving latest updates to all similarly Behaviour Subject pass latest data.

Add one service as myService and add following code
public myData: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject([]); updateData(data): void { this.myData.next(data); }

then call updateDatafrom where you want to send data to others. this.myService.updateData("Test"); You can pass any type of data here like object,array etc. Then on other component where you want this data write following code this.myService.myData.subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); }); You will get data. You can write above in any component where you want data.

Comment: thanks, issue is not with passing the data , the table loads and updates the content as expected. Only thing is , if i try to use sort it does not work.
I have used sort before on ```MatTableDataSource``` and it works without any issue with same code as given in question.

Comment: Okay, That's Great.I shared Bhaviour Subject working in details Hence to get you  idea for your question.